# Storekit Framework

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, storekit

I am new to iPhone development.

i would like to know about the storekit framework...

could you people please help me out to know about storekit and how it works ...

Thanks for your time

Comment: possible duplicate of [Design tips for StoreKit in iPhone OS 3.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042640/design-tips-for-storekit-in-iphone-os-3-0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple's documentation is now full-flavored:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html